# Overwrite without getting Do you really want to write to it (y/n)? in vim editor

Tags: vim

How to get rid of the message mentioned in the title of the post

Comment: As a general rule, overriding confirmation steps like that is a really bad idea.  It may well be that 99% of the time, you are sure you want to do whatever it is.  That other 1% of the time, you find yourself screaming "What have I done??!?!" about two seconds after it is too late to save yourself from massive mental trauma as you watch hours (or days) of work go into the bitbucket.

Comment: my file is being read by some program continously and based on the change the output keeps on change, so it will be very convinent to keep on change and save the file instead of pressing "y" on every change, besides i dont have any important data in the file and all i want to know is that if it is possible or not.

Comment: I don't completely understand your response, but it sounds as though you might want to investigate the program that is continuously reading your file.

Comment: No. I am testing a program which continuously reads a file and based on it the output is generated. In order to test the program with various inputs i need to be able to change the text file continuously which will speed up the testing process. For doing the same i want to be able to save the file without warning me since it takes extra key strokes on every save. I am not bothered losing data as i had mentioned in the previous post.

Answer (score 1):

From vims help on :w!:

```
                            *:w!*
:[range]w[rite]! [++opt] {file}
            Write the specified lines to {file}.  Overwrite an
            existing file.
```

Or is it this you are after?:

```
                *'confirm'* *'cf'* *'noconfirm'* *'nocf'*
'confirm' 'cf'      boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When 'confirm' is on, certain operations that would normally
    fail because of unsaved changes to a buffer, e.g. ":q" and ":e",
    instead raise a |dialog| asking if you wish to save the current
    file(s).  You can still use a ! to unconditionally |abandon| a buffer.
    If 'confirm' is off you can still activate confirmation for one
    command only (this is most useful in mappings) with the |:confirm|
    command.
    Also see the |confirm()| function and the 'v' flag in 'guioptions'.
```

Or perhaps even autowrite/autowriteall:

```
                 *'autowrite'* *'aw'* *'noautowrite'* *'noaw'*
'autowrite' 'aw'    boolean (default off)
            global
    Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
    :next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!,
    :make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^ command; and when a :buffer, CTRL-O, CTRL-I,
    '{A-Z0-9}, or `{A-Z0-9} command takes one to another file.
    Note that for some commands the 'autowrite' option is not used, see
    'autowriteall' for that.

             *'autowriteall'* *'awa'* *'noautowriteall'* *'noawa'*
'autowriteall' 'awa'    boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Like 'autowrite', but also used for commands ":edit", ":enew", ":quit",
    ":qall", ":exit", ":xit", ":recover" and closing the Vim window.
    Setting this option also implies that Vim behaves like 'autowrite' has
    been set.
```

A great future in vims help system is that you type something and then press "ctrl-d", vim will then display all matching entries:

```
:help autowrite ctrl-d
'autowrite' 'autowriteall' 'noautowrite' 'noautowriteall'
```

What you also can do is to have vim write to file as soon as the focus changes by adding this to your .vimrc file:

```
au FocusLost * :wa
```

Comment: autowrite did not help, because the problem is overwrite.